# How do you get data and bind to a table?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-ajax

I am trying to get data from a database and just bind the output to a table. I am using AJAX because some of my other codes won't allow me to mix with the IEnumerable. It doesn't seem to run the command and never trips breakpoints... Not sure what I might be doing wrong. I have scoured the internet and can't seem to find a solution or anything close, just broken code. It is loading the JS and even if I reference JS it still has the same behavior...

Index

```
 @model Rabbit.Application.Models.Onboarding.Client
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Areas/Onboarding/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}



<h2> Clients</h2>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="OpenAddPopup();">Add New Client</button><br /><br />
  <fieldset>
<table table id="tblClient" class="table">  
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>companyName</th>
            <th>PhoneNo</th>
            <th>ContactPerson</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
        </tbody>

        </table>
</fieldset>


<script type="text/javascript">
    //Load Data in Table when documents is ready
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $.ajax({
            url: "/Clients/GetAllClients",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result)
            {
                console.log(data);
                if (result) {
                    //itetrate thorugh each record and bind it to td
                    var html = '';
                    $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                         html += '<tr>';
                         html += + '<td>' + item.companyName + '</td>' 
                           html += + '<td>' + item.PhoneNo + '</td>' 
                           html += + '<td>' + item.ContactPerson + '</td>' 
                           html += + '<td>' + item.Email + '</td>' 
                           html += + '<td>' + item.Address + '</td>'
                           html += +'</tr>';
                });
                    $('#tbody').html(html);
                },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

Controller

```
public IActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}

public JsonResult GetAllClients()
{
            
    var clientlist = (from client in _context.Client
                       select client).ToList();
    return Json(clientlist);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After I tested it, it seems that this is just your grammar problem.

First,if you don't have a data variable,you need to delete `console.log(data);`.

Second,you should change `html += + '<td>' + item.companyName + '</td>'` to `html += '<td>' + item.companyName + '</td>'`.The same is true for the following, remove the `+` behind the `=`.

Third,you should change `$('#tbody').html(html);` to `$('.tbody').html(html);`,because you are using `class="tbody"`.And you need to add a `}` after this,and add `)` after the last one `}`.Because overall you are missing a `}` and a `)`.

Fourth，if `$(document)` reports an error, you can add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` before `<script type="text/javascript">`.

Below is my test code,it works fine：

```
@model BindTable.Models.Client

<h2> Clients</h2>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal" onclick="OpenAddPopup();">Add New Client</button><br /><br />
  <fieldset>
<table table id="tblClient" class="table">  
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>companyName</th>
            <th>PhoneNo</th>
            <th>ContactPerson</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Address</th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="tbody">
        </tbody>

        </table>
</fieldset>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //Load Data in Table when documents is ready
    $(document).ready(function () {
          $.ajax({
            url: "/Client/GetAllClients",
            type: "GET",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (result)
            {
                
                if (result) {
                    //itetrate thorugh each record and bind it to td
                    var html = '';
                    $.each(result, function (key, item) {
                         html += '<tr>';
                         html += '<td>' + item.companyName + '</td>' 
                           html += '<td>' + item.phoneNo + '</td>' 
                           html += '<td>' + item.contactPerson + '</td>' 
                           html += '<td>' + item.email + '</td>' 
                           html += '<td>' + item.address + '</td>'
                           html += '</tr>';
                    });
                    $('.tbody').html(html);
               }
            },
            error: function (errormessage) {
                    alert(errormessage.responseText);
                }
            });
        })
</script>
```

Test Result:
[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks. I agree. After cleaning up the ajax I had gotten it working.